# How to make SQL Execute command retry every 5 minutes 10 times if exception occur

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem I want to solve. 
I wanna write to database, but what I wonder is how can I retry to write to DB, if it fails. Like I want the task to retry if it fails writing to DB.

How can I IMplement logic that makes the SQL writing to DB retry every 5 minutes for example for 10 retries?

```
public async Task<string> Handler()
{
       DoStuff1,2,3();
}

public async Task<string> Dostuff1,2,3()
{
    try
    {

      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.CommandText = "InsertData";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Data", "TestData"));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
    }
}
```

My new attempt: Which of these should be correct?

```
public async Task<string> Handler()
{
       DatabaseSQLLogic1,2,3();
}


public async Task<string> DatabaseSQLLogic1,2,3()
{
     var success = false;
     var count = 0;

     while(!success && count < 10)
     {
       try
       {
           using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                 {
                     connection.Open();
                     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                     {

                         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                         cmd.Connection = connection;
                         cmd.CommandText = "InsertData";
                         cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Data", "TestData"));
                         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                         return true;
                     }
                 }
             }
         success = true;
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
         Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred doing the thing: {ex}");
         count += 1;
       }
     }

     // if success is still false, that means we our loop above failed after 10 attempts
     if(success == false)
     {
       Console.WriteLine("Failed to do the thing after 10 attempts");
     }
}
```

or

```
public async Task<string> Handler()
{
     var success = false;
     var count = 0;

     while(!success && count < 10)
     {
       try
       {
          DatabaseSQLLogic1,2,3();
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
         Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred doing the thing: {ex}");
         count += 1;
       }
     }

     // if success is still false, that means we our loop above failed after 10 attempts
     if(success == false)
     {
       Console.WriteLine("Failed to do the thing after 10 attempts");
     }
}






public async Task<string> DatabaseSQLLogic1,2,3()
{

      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
       {
           connection.Open();
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
           {

               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               cmd.Connection = connection;
               cmd.CommandText = "InsertData";
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Data", "TestData"));
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               return true;
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any database code here.

Comment: The best way to retry something that fails is to **find out why it failed**. `Console.WriteLine("Error")` doesn't do that.

Comment: That code wont compile as is. Please post the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Take "database" out of this question, as it can be replaced with any piece of logic.

```cs
var success = false;
var count = 0;

while(!success && count < 10)
{
  try
  {
    DoThing(); // database call, webservice call, etc
    success = true;
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred doing the thing: {ex}");
    count += 1;
  }
}

// if success is still false, that means we our loop above failed after 10 attempts
if(success == false)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Failed to do the thing after 10 attempts");
}
```

Of course, replace `Console.WriteLine` with actual log statements.

Comment: In the DoThing();

Do I need to trycatch in therE?

Comment: If the inside of `DoThing` is a black box, then all you can do is trycatch outside of it. If you control `DoThing`, then you should throw an exception on any known errors you come across, and let this loop outside do the retry logic.

Comment: Could you provide an example with the code I updated in the thread?

Comment: Literally put that code inside the try/catch, or call it in-place of the `DoThing`

Answer (score 0):

A temperamental legacy system required retry logic for reading data in flat files.

Here are some suggestions to follow based on this experience.

1. Check the type of error generated and only retry the update for the applicable errors. (Connection errors could not be retried for us, but timeout errors were OK to retry.)
2. Set a retry count limit constant and limit retries to that value. (3 strikes and you're out works for us.)
3. Pause the processing for a short time span (~1 second or so) between retries. This gives the system time to free up resources for the next retry.
4. Generate a retry count limit exceeded error message when this occurs and report the last error that caused the retry attempt to fail.

Comment: public async Task<string> Handler()
{
       DoStuff1,2,3();
}

Let's say that I catch the exception in the public async Task<string> Handler()
{
       DoStuff1,2,3();
}

Should I also have the try catch in the DoStuff function?

Comment: Before deciding how to divide the processing across functions, I suggest that you answer the implied question asked by Dour High Arch as to why you are encountering errors while attempting to do database updates.  Resolving that question may eliminate the need to write retry logic for this process. Perhaps you have a good reason for doing so, but that reason has not yet been described.